# Name changes for a few methods

Tags: support, api-v2

The following method names have been changed for reasons of consistency.

- /access-tokens/{accessTokens}/read is now [/access-tokens/{accessTokens}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-access-tokens)
- /filter/create is now [/filters/create](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter)
- /filter/{filters}/read is now [/filters/{filters}](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter)

The old methods are still available, and in fact just proxy to the new names.  I strongly encourage all consumers to migrate to the new names as soon as possible, as the proxies will be removed *eventually*.

I strongly suspect these will be the last top-level method changes before V2.0 is completely frozen.

Comment: "The old methods are still available, and in fact just proxy to the new names." Ah, so *that's* why my unit tests didn't catch that one.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison yeah, wanted to give at least a couple weeks for everyone to move off of these (admittedly, lesser used) methods.  Proxy seemed to be the sanest behavior.

Comment: One other question... didn't there use to be a `/filter/read` method? Is that the same as `/filters/{filters}` now?